# Laravel - Model and Function

Tags: laravel-4

I have some table like the follows:

```
id
name
parent_id
...
```

The parent_id is the id from the same table itself as it is something simple. For example:

```
id: 1
name: abc
parent_id: 0

id: 2
name: abc_parent
parent_id: 1

id: 3
name: another
parent_id: 1
```

How can I get the "name" inside some function in that model? Something like...

```
public function parentName()
{
    $pid = this->parent_id;
    /// return self::find($pid)->name; ### this does not actually work
}
```

Should I create a separate function and pass the parent_id to it? or is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, define a parent [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
  public function parent() {
    return $this->hasOne('Model', 'parent_id');
  }
}
```

This will allow you to use the relationship like `$item->parent->name`.

If you want something like `$item->parentName`, you can make an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) as an alias to the relationship.

```
public function getParentNameAttribute() {
  return $this->parent->name;
}
```

You'd then be able to do `$item->parentName`.